# Composing slices into a multidimensional slice for numpy array slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have two slice objects defined along one dimension each, is it possible to combine them to get a multidimensional slice object that can be used to slice a numpy array?

```
mat = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=np.uint8)
s1 = slice(0,5)
s2 = slice(0,5)
mat[s1,s2]  # I want to achieve this effect with one slice object    
slice2d = slice(s1, s2)  # does not throw an error
mat[slice2d]  # but this does not work
```

Comment: Must it be a slice object? `tup2d = (s1, s2)` is a single object and `mat[tup2d]` is the same as `mat[s1, s2]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @unutbu, what would be a multi-dimensional slice is actually a `tuple` or `list` of `slice` objects, then:

```
slice2d = (s1, s2)
mat[slice2d]
```

will work. Similarly, you can extend this to 3-D, ..., N-D arrays:

```
slice3d = (s1, s2, s3)
...
sliceNd = (s1, s3, s3, ..., sN)
```

Comment: Thanks. I find it curious though that the arguments to the slice constructor do not need to be integers. Can my `slice(s1,s2)` above be used for anything?

Comment: @SeanMackesey yes, they can be used in anything that accepts a sequence of slice objects, like the `np.ndarray` object...