# how to compose n-dimensional slices to get a cannonical ndslice

Tags: python, pytorch, slice, numpy-ndarray

Consider a portion of an ndarray `x` formed by two consecutive slices (I'm using numpy in the example, but the question is more general.  I'm actually using pytorch in my application.):

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(4 * 10 * 12 * 7).reshape(4, 10, 12, 7)
first = (slice(None), 3, slice(3, 9))
second = (2, slice(1, 3), slice(5))
out = x[first][second]
```

I want a way to get a *canonical*, combined ndslice as a function of `x.shape`, `first` and `second`. E.g.

```py
combined = compose(x.shape, first, second)
assert np.equal(x[first][second], x[combined]).all()
assert combined == (2, 3, slice(4, 6), slice(5))
```

I am only interested in "simple" ndslices consisting of: a single int, a single slice object, or a tuple of any combination of ints and slice objects.

By *canonical*, I mean that the resulting combined slice should uniquely identify that subset of `x`.
For example here is another way to access the same segment and it should lead to the same combined ndslice:

```
other_first = (slice(2, 4), slice(None), slice(2, 7))
other_second = (0, 3, slice(2, -1), slice(5))
combined = compose(x.shape, other_first, other_second)
assert np.equal(x[other_first][other_second], x[combined]).all()
assert combined == (2, 3, slice(4, 6), slice(5))
```

Because slices support "None" and negative indexes, we will need the shape of `x` in order to get a canonical ndslice.

#### Related Questions

Note that I am interested in `x[first][second]` which different (in general) from `x[first, second]` discussed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945463/composing-slices-into-a-multidimensional-slice-for-numpy-array-slicing).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still interested if someone happens to know of a builtin or more elegant solution (even if specific to numpy or pytorch), but this is the general, home-grown solution I came up with:

```py
def compose_single(lhs, rhs, length):
    out = range(length)[lhs][rhs]
    return out if isinstance(out, int) else slice(out.start, out.stop, out.step)

def compose(shape, first, second):
    def ensure_tuple(ndslice):
        return ndslice if isinstance(ndslice, tuple) else (ndslice,)

    first = ensure_tuple(first)
    second = ensure_tuple(second)

    out = list(first) + [slice(None)] * (len(shape) - len(first))
    remaining_dims = [i for i, s in enumerate(out) if isinstance(s, slice)]
    for i, rhs in zip(remaining_dims, second):
        out[i] = compose_single(out[i], rhs, length=shape[i])
    return tuple(out)
```

Note that the canonical output will not use negative or None starts or ends. So I've updated the test cases below:

```py
shape = (4, 10, 12, 7)
first = (slice(None), 3, slice(3, 9))
second = (2, slice(1, 3), slice(5))
expected_combined = (2, 3, slice(4, 6, 1), slice(0, 5, 1))

assert compose(shape, first, second) == expected_combined

other_first = (slice(2, 4), slice(None), slice(2, 7))
other_second = (0, 3, slice(2, -1), slice(5))

assert compose(shape, other_first, other_second) == expected_combined
```